# Thresholding in Android using opencv

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

Not sure if this is the right way to ask, but please help. I have an image of a dented car. I have to process it and highlight the dents and return the number of dents. I was able to do it reasonably well with the following result:

[image]

[image]

The matlab code is:

```
  img2=rgb2gray(i1);
  imshow(img2);
  img3=imtophat(img2,strel('disk',15));
  img4=imadjust(img3);
  layer=img4(:,:,1);
  img5=layer>100 & layer<250;
  img6=imfill(img5,'holes');
  img7=bwareaopen(img6,5);
  [L,ans]=bwlabeln(img7);
  imshow(img7);
  I=imread(i1);
  Ians=CarDentIdentification(I);
```

However, when I try to do this using opencv, I get this:

[image]

With the following code:

```
   Imgproc.cvtColor(source, middle, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    Imgproc.equalizeHist(middle, middle);
    Imgproc.threshold(middle, middle, 150, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
```

Please tell me how can I obtain better results in opencv, and also how to count the dents? I tried findcontour() but it gives a very large number. I tried on other images as well, but I'm not getting proper results. 
Please help.

Comment: You do see that the threshold values you used in matlab and opencv are different?

Comment: Of course, I tried a lot of different values. Matlab has the function imtophat() as a result of which illumination becomes uniform and after adjusting the contrast, the dents appear very bright. So, these values do not work in opencv.

Comment: If you read precisely what imtophat is doing in matlab, you ca do the same in opencv, although there isn't a _direct_ filter for it.

Comment: That's exactly why I'm asking the question here. Can't find the exact process/code/thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you basically from the [*MATLAB* site](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imtophat.html), `imtophat` does - Top-hat filtering computes the morphological opening of the image (using imopen) and then subtracts the result from the original image.

You could do this in OpenCV with the following steps:

Step 1: Get the **disk** structuring element

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (15, 15))
```

Step 2: Compute opening of the image and then subtract the result from the original image

```
tophat = cv2.morphologyEx(v, cv2.MORPH_TOPHAT, kernel)
```

This gives following result -

[image: TopHat]

Step 3 - Now you could just manually threshold it or use Otsu -

```
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(tophat, 17, 255, 0)
```

which gives you the following image -

[image: topHat thresholded]

Since the OP wants the code in Java, here is the probable code in `Java`:

```
private Mat topHat(Mat image)
{
Mat element  = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(15, 15), new Point (0, 0));
Mat dst = new Mat;
Imgproc.morphologyEx(image, dst, Imgproc.MORPH_TOPHAT, element, new Point(0, 0));

return dst;
}
```

Make sure you do this on a gray scale image (`CvType.8UC1`) and then you can threshold suitably.

Comment: Thanks, but this is for c++ right? I can't find an equivalent to tophat() for Java. Also in the morphing process, I can not simply assign integer values. It asks for parameters- type (ellipse), size, anchor.

Comment: These functions are there in opencv for Java, C++ and python. The code I posted is in python because it is faster for me to see results. If you are using `android` you could always use NDK C++. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272327/opencv4android-blank-image-after-using-morphologyex)

Comment: Well, the reason for this may be the fact that I'm a newbie or anything, but I had results in C++. Even in the opencv documentation, explanation is given for C++ and python. The problem is non of this working in Android studio.

Comment: Morphology function in Java only has erosion and dilation.

Comment: Opening is erosion + dilation. I updated the code with Java, let me know if it works as I don't have opencv for java. Just advice, when I was a newbie and learning I was also happy to get the code for me. It'll help you in the long run if you try some stuff yourself (I already gave you the way in python and an example link of how it can be done in android).

Comment: I hope you mean _critical_ by _offensive_. Just some advice from personal experience. Anyways, let me know if it works in Java.

Comment: The morphology code (5th line), is it an assignment? Function can't work as it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150160/discussion-between-rick-m-and-harshita).